# Type value mismatch with list template

Tags: c++, list, templates, type-mismatch

How can I solve `error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::list'`?

My classes:

TrieNode.h:

```
    template <class T>
    class TrieNode {    
       public:
           char subStr;
           list<TrieNode> childs;
           TrieNode<T> parent;
```

StrTrieNode.h:

```
    template<class T>
        class StrTrieNode: public TrieNode<T> {
        public:
            list<StrCy> vars;   
        };
```

StrTrie.cpp:

```
    template<class StrCy>
    bool StrTrie<StrCy>::searchVars(const char* word) {
           ....
           std::list<StrTrieNode>:: iterator it;         // error!!!
           ....
    }
```

Comment: `StrTrieNode` is not a type, it's a template.

Comment: Where did you define `StrTrie`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
std::list<StrTrieNode<StrCy>  >:: iterator it;
```

Comment: Be sure to fix `list<TrieNode> childs` as well: it should be TrieNode<T>. Also, be sure to write `> >` instead of `>>` - notice the whitespace.

Comment: That probably also needs a `typename` at the beginning: `typename std::list<StrTrieNode<StrCy> >::iterator it;`